AG Grid: wait for animations to be finished
We have a Playwright test suite that tests our Angular application. On some pages we have AG-Grid grids and the tests manipulates and asserts on the AG-Grid however we are facing some instabilities and as far as I can tell it is due to the fact that the animations (like expanding the rows) can cause other elements to close. So when the page loads and we wait for the loading indicator to go away, then the test will immediately start to interact with the grid. We have two cases where it appears that the test acts too fast:

Clicking the page-size selector too fast will make it close again
Hovering over a cell to see the tooltip will make the tooltip disappear

The simple way is to add delays but I would like to avoid arbitrary delays as much as possible and instead react to changes in the DOM.
So for this I would like to know if there is a way to tell if AG-Grid is totally loaded, rendered and animated? Either by observing classes or through the Grid API reference?
EDIT:
I hope this minimal reproducible example demonstrates by issue:
using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
await using var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions
{
    Headless = false,
});
var context = await browser.NewContextAsync();

var page = await context.NewPageAsync();
await page.GotoAsync("https://c5kg58.csb.app/");
await page.GetByLabel("Page Size").ClickAsync();
await page.WaitForTimeoutAsync(1000); // Let animations happen resulting in the page size option disappearing
await page.GetByRole(AriaRole.Option, new() { Name = "50" }).ClickAsync();

The delay is a bit arbitrary but aims to demonstrate that if the page size is clicked before the animations are over then the box disappears

I'd recommend trying out the firstDataRendered event. Maybe you could add a class yourself in that event to indicate things are done loading.

The firstDataRendered event fires the first time data is rendered into the grid. It will only be fired once unlike rowDataUpdated which is fired on every data change.

https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-miscellaneous-firstDataRendered

Hmm might work but I wish there was something like it that could also work if you start to interact with the grid. If I change page, quick filter etc. the same animations will occur and I'd like to be able to wait for those to

I checked and it does trigger before the animations has finished. I might still be able to use it as a workaround but it would be nice if I didn't have to
